# How to transfer ERC20 token from one account to another account but paying the transaction fee from third account?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, erc-20, etherscan

I want to transfer token from account A to account B by paying transaction fee from account C.I have tried the following logic but token transfer from contract to contract mean contract transfer token to itself.

tell me is it possible or not ?
if it is not possible then what would be alternative to achieve this goal.

> account address from which token has to transfer = TA
>
> account address from which transaction fee has to pay = PA
>
> account address to which token has to transfer = RA

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray,contractAddress,{from:TA}) 

var rawTransaction = {"from":PA, "gasPrice":data.result,"gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex(100000),"to":contractAddress,"value":"0x0","data":contract.methods.transfer(RA, amount).encodeABI(),"nonce":web3.utils.toHex(count)} 

var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction,{ chain: transactionNetwork})

transaction.sign(privateKey of PA)
```

Comment: PA can call `tokenContract.transferFrom(TA, RA, amount)`, but `TA` must first call `tokenContract.approve(PA, amount)` to authorize it. They can do that just once and authorize whatever amount they want (e.g. 2**256-1 to roughly mean "infinite").

Comment: can share the some code example ?

Comment: I already did? `tokenContract.transferFrom(<address of the token holder>, <address of the recipient>, <amount to transfer>)`

Comment: If you need to build a raw transaction like you're doing above, use `contract.methods.transferFrom(TA, RA, amount).encodeABI()`. The call to `approve` would be from TA and use `contract.methods.approve(PA, amount).encodeABI()`.

Comment: TA have 0 ether balance.it can not call approve method

Comment: TA is with 0 ether balance but have some erc-20 token
PA has ethers and has to pay fee of transfering fee from TA to RA .
suggest some way to do this

Comment: In a typical ERC20 contract, there's no way for a transfer to happen without the owner of the tokens sending a transaction.